# Script to automate data population once windows VM in GCP started

Tags: powershell, scripting, google-compute-engine, shell-scripting

I need to know if there is any way I can build a script which can be executed as soon as my windows VM is started in GCP. This script should(Other than RPA solution) be able to open a web browser and fill 3 consecutive pages(text fields, radio buttons, etc.) of my custom web-app and hit submit to the button.

Any suggestion how this kind of script is built or any sample script.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to populate data into 3 web forms using a Windows script that has to be executed at system boot.

1. Execute script at startup

   Put the script in [the startup folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-get-startup-folder-in-start-all-programs/d3f5486a-16c0-4e69-8446-c50dd35163f1).

   *You might need to change the folder options to see hidden folders.
2. Open multiple web pages from a script and pass parameters.

   Example BAT script (firefox)

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
start firefox.exe www.youtube.com google.com news.google.com
```

3. pass parameters to web forms

There are dozens of ways to achieve this depending on the programming language you want to use.

I recommend you to take a look into [this link](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/passing-data-between-pages-in-asp.net.htm) that explains 4 different methods to pass data to a website from a script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and thanks for taking the time to answer. :-) Here at Stack Exchange, we discourage the use of links in answers, as over time, those links go stale and the quality of the answers suffer as a result.  You are welcome to link a page for further detail or elaboration around your answer, but the content of your answer should stand alone in the body of your message without needing to read the links.